# How to get contact id after add a new contact in android?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-syncadapter

I use following code for new contacts added to phone.

```
private static void addContact(Account account, String name, String username,String phone,String email) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Adding contact: " + name);
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operationList = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
    builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
    builder.withValue(RawContacts.SYNC1, username);
    operationList.add(builder.build());

 //NAME adding area
    builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
    operationList.add(builder.build());

 // Phone Number adding area
    builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, phone);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK);
    operationList.add(builder.build());
    }
```

This code work fine for adding a new contact.

I want to update my contacts from server to phone. So **I need contact id** for updating purpose.

**Can I get contact id from above code?**. If anybody known share your answer.

If any questions or comments also welcome. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code,

```
ContentProviderResult[] res = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);

Uri myContactUri = res[0].uri;
int lastSlash = myContactUri.toString().lastIndexOf("/");
int length = myContactUri.toString().length();
int contactID = Integer.parseInt((String) myContactUri.toString().subSequence(lastSlash+1, length));
```

I hope this code help you..

Answer (score 1):

The bulk insert that you do with the operation list will return a list of results (URIs I think, but it's been a few months since I did this), I believe you can get the ID you want from the first of these results

```
 long rawContactId = ContentUris.parseId(rawContactUri);
```

Comment: I insert contacts one by one. Not bult insert.

Comment: And it's URI, not URL. :)

Comment: You're using an operations list. That's bulk queries (you have to apply batch)

Answer (score 1):

After Applying the badge and receive the last segment you receive:
ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID
If you want to get Contact_id you should make this query:

(rowId - is the  last segment you received before)

```
String[] projections = new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID};
String select = ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID + "= ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{rowId};
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projections, select, selectionArgs, null);
    String contactId = null;
    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
          Log.d("aaa","Couldn't find row: " + rowId);
          return null;
    }

    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
         int columnIndex;
         columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID);
         if (columnIndex == -1) {
               Log.d("aaa","Couldn't get contact id");
         } else {
               contactId = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
         }
    }

    cursor.close();
    return contactId;
```